# ResourceFunction cannot find cached local version

Tags: files-and-directories, localsymbol, resourcefunction

When I try to use `ResourceFunction` it doesn't find a file. I'm afraid it's because my user name on Windows include spaces and an "é".

```
ResourceFunction["AbundantNumber"][1]
```

> ResourceFunction::lfail: Failed to load resource function from LocalObject[file:///C:/Users/Juan%20Jos%C3%A9%20Alba/AppData/Roaming/Wolfram/Objects/Resources/6eb/6ebae805-287b-40a4-b883-c9c6330d8a61/download/1-0-0/DefinitionData]

```
Out[1] = $Failed[1]
```

It's not the first time I have problems because of my user name. Anyone knows a work around for this?

Comment: Are you using version 12.0 or later?

Comment: I'm using version 12.2.0.0

Comment: Look at `$ResourceSystemPath`.  See if you can figure out how to change the `PersistenceLocation` of type `"Local"`.  Maybe that will help. -- Or maybe it's `$PersistencePath` that need fixing. -- Maybe `$LocalBase`.  Maybe if you set `$LocalBase` to a valid directory, it will work.  (I don't know how to test.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 That doesn't work :(
Any others variables I can try?

Comment: @jjagmath — found your question while encountering the same problem, and the following did the trick for me.  `f=ResourceFunction["AbundantNumber"]; ResourceRemove[f]`  LMK if it works for you and we can post it as an official answer...

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier I don't get your suggestion. After `f=ResourceFunction["AbundantNumber"]; ResourceRemove[f]` you were able to use the function?

Comment: @jjagmath:  Correct (although I did it for a different function).  Try it and see if it works for you...

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier It didn't work